# (error "tactic failed: operator not supported, apply simplifier before invoking this strategy") in Z3

Tags: z3

I want to eliminate the expressions and convert the final result to cnf using z3, however, there is an error said "(error "tactic failed: operator not supported, apply simplifier before invoking this strategy")" what's the problem in the script?

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-var t Real)
(declare-var tc Real)
(declare-var t1 Real)
(declare-var t1c Real)
(assert
   (and 
      (not (and (and (<= 0.0 t)(<= 0.0 t1))(= t1c 2.0)(= tc 1.0)))
      (not (and (and (<= 0.0 t)(<= 0.0 t1))(< 2.0 t1c)(= tc 1.0)))
      (not (and (and (and (<= 0.0 t)(<= 0.0 t1))(< 1.0 tc)) (= t1c 2.0)))
      (not (and (and (and (<= 0.0 t)(<= 0.0 t1))(< 1.0 tc)) (< 2.0 t1c)))
      (or (and (and (and (<= 0.0 t)(<= 0.0 t1))(<= 0.0 t1c))(<= 0.0 tc)(< tc 1.0))
          (and (and (and (<= 0.0 t) (<= 0.0 t1))(<= 0.0 t1c))(< 1.0 tc)(< t1c 2.0))
          (and (and (and (<= 0.0 t)(<= 0.0 t1))(< 1.0 tc)) (= t1c 2.0))
          (and (and (and (<= 0.0 t) (<= 0.0 t1))(<= 0.0 t1c))
               (= tc 1.0)
               (or (and (and (and (<= 0.0 t) (<= 0.0 t1))(<= 0.0 t1c))
                        (< t1c  2.0)
                        (= tc 1.0)
                     )
                   (and (and (<= 0.0 t)(<= 0.0 t1))(= t1c 2.0)(= tc 1.0))
                )
           )
        )
   )
)
(apply (then  ctx-solver-simplify propagate-values  (par-then (repeat (or-else split-clause skip)) propagate-ineqs) tseitin-cnf))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tactics (e.g., `tseitin-cnf`) assume that some operators (e.g., `and`, `distinct`, ...) have been eliminated. In your example, the problem is the occurrence of the operator `and` nested inside the formula. You can eliminate it using the tactic `(! simplify :elim-and true)`.
Here is the updated script:

`(apply (then (! simplify :elim-and true) ctx-solver-simplify propagate-values  (par-then (repeat (or-else split-clause skip)) propagate-ineqs) tseitin-cnf))`

That being said, in the next release, we will make the tactics such as `tseitin-cnf` more "user friendly". That is, it will automatically apply the required transformations when needed.